# Use Android phone as display for RPi3

Tags: hardware, pi-3, display, vnc, peripherals

I have Raspberry Pi 3 (connected to LAN and Internet via Ethernet cable) with:

1. Wi-Fi hotspot settled up and working;
2. `TightVNC` server running at startup. I can connect to it using my PC or Android phone and it works just fine.

But I don't have any proper display to connect to my RPi. My question is can I use my smartphone only as display and control RPi with USB keyboard and mouse, not from the phone? I tried doing so both in watch-only mode and full control mode, but RPi just doesn't respond to KB and mouse input.

P.S. Sorry for my (maybe bad) English.

Edit: I can't just connect the peripherals to my phone because it lacks USB host function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace *tightVNC* by *x11vnc*, and configure the server side to use the port 5900 and the display 0.

Then connect to it with your usual vnc client. You should now interact on the same display with your keyboard and mouse on the rpi side, and with your touchpad on the phone side.
You can find more information here : http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/

Answer (score 0):

When using a vnc app on your phone to connect to TightVNC (as long as it is running) you should be able to connect peripherals to the RPi and see them on screen, if not perhaps try switching between the desktops.

Comment: what switching between desktop means?

Comment: (I wasnt able to reply to you in the comments so I hope you don't mind, I had to write it as another answer instead.) Sometimes it has more than one screen open however you can only see one at a time. Usually there is a button on screen that allows you to switch between the desktops. For some reason the RPi sometimes let you view one screen but put the cursor on the other.

Comment: I don't see any desktop switching buttons on my Pi, and also mouse pointer is there, but moving only by touchscreen, not mouse.

Comment: It depends what operating system you are running but usually the desktop button is a picture of 2 rectangles on the toolbar

Comment: Also i meant controls the cursor on the other screen rather than shows