# Android phone as display (through USB Cable)

Tags: android

I understand that [VNC has been used to enable viewing on an Android display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54218/40373), which requires a network.  I would like to be able to use the display (and ideally other Android resources) through a USB connection between the two devices.  Assume a network is not available for the exercise.

1. Has a project already built this capability? OR
2. Is said capability a matter of configuring settings on the rPi and downloading an App to the Android device?
3. USB is serial communications: would the Android 'resource' (phone's display) be represented as a 'file'?  Said 'file' to be a destination for video traffic?

Examples or tutorial links are appreciated: thank you.

Comment: it is possible that a USB connection could provide a serial port connection between the two devices ...... you could also use bluetooth